# EditText set text start 10dp from left border

Tags: android

Is possible in android EditText widget to set that text start 10dp from left border ? When I type something at the moment it is glued to left side and I need to put a little padding.

Comment: set  android:paddingLeft="10dp"  in edittext.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `android:padding` attribute.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

has a 10dp padding on all sides

you may just want to specify the left and right padding.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

Will make the padding on the left and right be 10dp.

Comment: This saved me having to go down a layout rabbit hole. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Use paddingStart (and paddingEnd)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="#646464"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
/>
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Did this really solve your problem? setting padding on xml doesn't seem to apply on EditText for me. I solved it some other way. Placed the EditText in side a RelativeLayout view and applied the padding to that RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox_bg">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/emailText"
            android:text="text inside"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
         </RelativeLayout>
```

as i had issues with EditText background RelativeLayout and set the EditText background transparent. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I solved using android:layout_marginLeft/android:layout_marginRight. Padding just changed the cursor position.

Comment: **Padding just changed the cursor position** and that was what he wanted to do .