# Padding for hint text inside EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, padding

I want to be able to add padding to the text that is displayed inside the EditText, using

```
android:hint="some text"
```

If I only add padding for the EditText regularly, it adds the padding for the whole view. And i want it for the text that gives a hint for the user, what needs to be entered. If someone knows how to do this, please give me a feedback.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You may find your solution in this answer:
[EditText set text start 10dp from left border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751145/edittext-set-text-start-10dp-from-left-border)

It helped me to achieve the padding for hint in username field:

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="30dp"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:background="@drawable/bkg_login_txt_usuario"
 android:hint="@string/hint_username"
 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
 android:singleLine="true" >
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated. Use `android:maxLines="1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:drawablePadding` which denotes the padding between the drawable and the hint texts.

Answer (score -2):

Use the TextChangedListener and a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to monitor the text inside the EditText. Use the TextWatcher check to see if the EditText is empty and set the padding, otherwise remove the padding.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough about what I want to do. I edited my question and added a picture. As you can see, the text that gives a hint for the user, what should one enter in the edittext field, is not stick to its left edge. It has a padding. I don't know if that can be accomplished using TextWatcher.. Also when the user enters some text, I want the distance (padding) to be maintained.