# How to change text alignment by measurement?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application i have a an `EditText` that is aligned to the left.
I would like the text in that EditText to be a bit more to the right by like 5dp or some other form of measurement that is not "left" or "center".

How to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: android:paddingLeft="5dp"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EditText set text start 10dp from left border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751145/edittext-set-text-start-10dp-from-left-border)

Answer (score 1):

Use padding in EditText

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
   android:gravity="left"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped.

This is actually a duplicate i just phrased my question wrong when i tried to search for an answer.
Sorry :(